# Finding the number of female white tigers with a Venn Diagram.

Tags: combinatorics

The question goes:  In a Zoo, there are 6 Bengal white tigers and 7 Bengal royal tigers. Out of these tigers, 5 are males and 10 are either Bengal royal tigers or males. Find the number of female Bengal white tigers in the Zoo.

As per my understanding, there are four possible sets here: sets of Bengal white, Bengal Royal, Male and female tigers respectively.
The only given data I find here n(BW)=6, n(BR)=7, n(M)=5, n(BR U M) =10, n(FBW)=?

Please give me some hints on how to start solving these kinds of problems (related to cardinality) where the given data at first glance seems too insufficient.

Comment: Can you find how many tigers are both male and royal tigers? Then, you can find how many male white tigers there are, and from there, how many female white tigers.

Comment: I think the key is that, if the tiger is not "Bengal Royal or male", this means that it is *neither* Bengal Royal *nor* male, i.e. it must be Bengal White *and* female.

Comment: In general, I'd approach these sorts of problems by drawing a [Venn Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram). One circle in this case would be being male, and the other being royal.

Comment: Are you allowed to assume that every tiger is either male or female but not both? Or are there gender neutral tigers too? Fluids? "++" (object oriented)?

Comment: I think this is an old problem that lacks DEI (diversity, equity and inclusion), and has to be closed.

Comment: @markvs I think we can safely assume that every tiger is either male or female but not both since it is supposed to be a beginner level problem

Comment: If the problem is given to elementary school children in Berkeley, CA, I would assume that the gender of tigers can be all over the spectrum.

Comment: @markvs Ah, that makes sense, but here in India and Nepal It is common assume male and female gender (at least in maths problems) if not explicitly stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of *female* royal tigers is $10-5=5$, since "royal or male" completely includes "male" – we are taking set difference here. Then a simple chain of arithmetic gives us $7-5=2$ male royals, $5-2=3$ male whites and $6-3=3$ female whites.

Implicit in the question statement is that all objects of interest are either white or royal and either male or female.

Comment: Thanks @Parcly, I didn't know I could do set difference with cardinality!